# Remote SPARQL query in C/C++

Tags: sparql, rdf, endpoint, wikidata, rasqal

I need to process responses of RDF graphs querying with SPARQL, using C/C++ code.

I'm trying to query [Wikidata](https://query.wikidata.org/sparql) endpoint with SPARQL, using the [Rasqal](https://librdf.org/rasqal/) library, but it doesn't work (HTTP 403 problem).

The problem (probably) is in the cURL configuration of Rasqal (last updated - 2014). Querying directly from cURL with command line works succesfully.

I have searched in Github, and have tried with [fuseki-c](https://github.com/vorachet/fuseki-c) and [libsparqlclient](https://github.com/bbcarchdev/libsparqlclient), but they aren't deserialization for RDF objects (or triplestore management).

Could you please give information about other libraries to query remote endpoints with SPARQL, and can to manage RDF objects (deserialize rdf+xml)?

Thanks!

**[EDIT]**

Specifically, I need to replace Apache Jena with a C/C++ library, for queries and deserialization of RDF results.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how fuseki-c doesn't provide serialization for RDF objects?
You also mention 'manage RDF objects' at the end of your question; what do you mean by that?

Comment: @Thomas I've edited the question with more details. I apologize, fuseki-c doesn't provide deserialization, such as Apache Jena. About "manage RDF object", I need to manipulate the triples of the response to Wikidata, like objects (in Apache Jena, ResultSet, Model, RDFNode, etc) to identify patterns. Thanks for your comment!